# ¿Cómo crear un repositorio local utilizando Git?

Tags: git

Estoy trabajando con *Eclipse* y para el trabajo en equipo utilizaremos *Git*. Necesito crear un repositorio local porque por la privacidad de los datos no pueden encontrarse en la nube, para que los demás del trabajo puedan acceder al repositorio que estará en mi computadora.

Nos comentaron de algunas aplicaciones como *GitLab*, *GitStack* y *Gitea*, pero no permite multiusuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes ya tener inicializado tu proyecto con git, si no lo tienes puedes hacerlo con:

```
git init
```

[Dejo documentación para inicializar un proyecto](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Fundamentos-de-Git-Obteniendo-un-repositorio-Git).

Ahora, para crear un repositorio local como servidor debes clonar el repositorio que ya tienes utilizando la instrucción `--bare`, como el ejemplo que dejo a continuación:

```
git clone --bare /d/path/my_project my_project_server
```

Dejo link de la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) para este caso.

También dejo una pequeña parte de lo que dice la documentación:

> ### 4.2 Git en el servidor: obtener Git en un servidor
>
> Para configurar inicialmente cualquier servidor Git, debe exportar un repositorio existente a un nuevo repositorio básico, un repositorio que no contiene un directorio de trabajo. Esto es generalmente fácil de hacer. Para clonar su repositorio para crear un nuevo repositorio básico, ejecute el comando de clonación con la opción bare. Por convención, los nombres de directorios de repositorios desnudos terminan con el sufijo .git, así:
>
> ```
> $ git clone --bare my_project my_project.git
> Cloning into bare repository 'my_project.git'...
> done.
> ```

Una vez hecho esto ya tendrás el proyecto del cual todos podrán clonar.

Ojo que los demás deben clonar sin utilizar la instrucción `--bare`, solo clonar de la forma básica:

```
git clone /pathserver/my_project_server /d/path/my_project
```

Comment: El `git init` hay que correrlo estando parado en el directorio raiz del proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

La referencia de git que deberías consultar es este artículo: [Git on the Server - Getting Git on a Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)

Necesitas una máquina que haga las veces del repositorio remoto, del mismo modo que harían en la nube GitHub, GitLab...
En esa máquina crearemos un directorio al que podemos llamar `git_server`.
Todos los repositorios que creemos los guardaremos aquí.
Necesitamos que la máquina esté siempre escuchando, para ello iniciamos un demonio con [`git daemon`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon).

Abre una consola apuntando a la carpeta `git_server`.
Te comparto un comando habitual para arrancar el demonio, aunque dependiendo de tus necesidades concretas puedes configurarlo como necesites.

```
git daemon --base-path=. --export-all --enable=receive-pack --reuseaddr --informative-errors --verbose
```

Llenaremos el directorio con repositorios bare de la forma que describe la documentación de git que he enlazado al principio.
Para iniciar el repositorio bare lo haremos con el comando:

```
git --bare init <repo-name>.git --shared
```

El sufijo `.git` es una convención.

Por tu pregunta deduzco que ya tienes un repositorio git con un historial que no querrás perder.
Déjame llamar `git_original` a este directorio.
Si abres una consola en este directorio y escribes `git remote -v` deberías ver que no tienes ningún repositorio remoto.
Añade a `git_original` tu recién creado repositorio bare con este comando:

```
git remote add origin git://<remote-machine-name>/<git_server>
```

Para rellenar el repositorio bare simplemente ejecuta desde `git_original` un comando `push`.
Sólo podrás ejecutar `push` si el dameon está corriendo.